# How to save a awt Image in java where i have the image data in String and which is in the AWT image object format

Tags: java, image, awt

I am using REST webservices to get an image from mongodb database. Once i got the image i am saving in the server and i will get the image in AWT image object using the method ImageIo.read method .But my concern is i should return the image object in string format because i am using Spring boot which internally convert the object in to JSON format. So if i invoke this webservice then it will return the image data as string . I need to convert that String again to awt Image object because then only i can save my image. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: How is the binary data of the image encoded into a `String`?

Comment: because i am returning the Image object from the webservice .

Comment: and in the controller i am getting the webservice data as string

Comment: using buffered stream

Comment: BUT, how is the binary data been converted to a `String`?  Is it using a something like a base64 process or something else?  Without knowing how the binary data is encoded, it's going to hard to know how to decode it

Comment: no yar ...im using this way Image image=ImageIO..read(file)

Comment: im using Spring boot for writing webservice.This internally converts the image to JSON. So when i am getting the data from webservice it is in String and  JSON format

Comment: Yes, but we to know "HOW" Sprint boot is converting your binary Image to JSON/`String`...Personally, if I were you, I'd take control of the process and use base64 to convert the binary data to text yourself, before you pass it off to your webserver...

Comment: But how u will again get the image in controller?

Comment: ImageIO.write -> Base64.encode (text) -> Webservice -> Database -> WebService -> Base64.deoce (image) -> ImageIO.read ...